# How the get the port of the instance in Django settings

Tags: django

Is there any way to get which port Django is working on in settings? I am trying to find it in socket but I couldn't manage to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest you can get is probably:

```
import django.core.management.commands.runserver as runserver
cmd = runserver.Command()
print('http://' + cmd.default_addr + ':' + cmd.default_port)
```

Comment: this will return incorrect port if a non default port is being used

Answer (score 2):

Dont know if this is what you want but I found this in the django documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Check out `SERVER_PORT`.

It can be accessed inside of a view by using:

```
port_number = request.META['SERVER_PORT']
```

Comment: There is no problem to find it in views, I need to get it in settings, so I cannot use request.

Comment: The issue you are going to have is most web servers allow connections on a number of port numbers. So your not going to have just on port. For example if your site can use both http and https then you are going to have people connecting at least on `:80` and `:443`. What's your reasoning for wanting the port number in settings?

Comment: NGINX accepts connections in 80 or 443 classically and it redirects to the Django service which works in a different port locally.

There will be two services working in different ports for the same Django project. And only templates will be in different folders in those two services. For example x.com will redirect into service works with 8000 port, y.com will be for 8001. if the post is 8000, template folder will be xtemplates, if y, ytemplates.